# Splash Screen disappeared after Application.OnCreate was overridden

Tags: xamarin.android, mvvmcross, oncreate

### Initial Issue

I need to register `ProcessLifecycleOwner` as described here [Xamarin.Android Architecture Components](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50820864/2346621) in my `Application.OnCreate` method.

But it had resulted in the error with `6.2.2` version of `MvvmCross`:

> `MvvmCross.Exceptions.MvxIoCResolveException`: Failed to resolve type `MvvmCross.ViewModels.IMvxAppStart` occurred

or just stuck on the `Splash Screen` with `6.2.3`.

---

### Fix

Those problems were fixed by advice from [Xamarin.Android mvvmcross app crashes when launching with intent filter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36646037/xamarin-android-mvvmcross-app-crashes-when-launching-with-intent-filter/36647066#36647066).

```cs
[Application]
public class App : MvxAndroidApplication<Setup, Core.App>
{
    public App(IntPtr reference, JniHandleOwnership transfer) :
        base(reference, transfer) { }

    public override void OnCreate()
    {
        MvxAndroidSetupSingleton
            .EnsureSingletonAvailable(ApplicationContext)
            .EnsureInitialized();

        base.OnCreate();
    }
}
```

### Current Issue

However `Splash Screen` dissapeared too, only blue background from `default theme` was left.

A workaround I've found:

```cs
public override void OnCreate()
{
    Task.Run(() => MvxAndroidSetupSingleton
                     .EnsureSingletonAvailable(ApplicationContext)
                     .EnsureInitialized());

    base.OnCreate();
}
```

But due to parallelism it is not reliable, sometimes works, sometimes crashes.

---

### Question

How `Splash Screen` can be restored?

Comment: First of all , i do not recommand you to use `Task,Run(()=>MvxAndroidSetupSingleton)..`, MvxAndroidSetupSingleton can be used to ensure the framework is up and running at any time , it may block your UI. If you use Task.Run(), you open a child thread then running `MvxAndroidSetupSingleton..`  , you could Using `Task.Wait()` to stuck on main thread for waiting while task is finished.

Comment: Thanks, but can you explain what to use instead of `MvxAndroidSetupSingleton` if you don't recommend it? Also, adding call to `.Wait()` for the task in workaround blocks `UI` too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your approach is most likely blocking on the UI thread which us causing the UI to block during the time that the expected splash screen is suppose to show.

Try using an async event handler to allow for a non blocking UI call

```
[Application]
public class App : MvxAndroidApplication<Setup, Core.App> {
    public App(IntPtr reference, JniHandleOwnership transfer) :
        base(reference, transfer) { 
        EnsureInitialized = onEnsureInitialized; //Subscribe to event
    }

    private event EventHandler EnsureInitialized = delegate { };

    private async void onEnsureInitialized(object sender, EventArgs args) {
        await Task.Run(() => MvxAndroidSetupSingleton.EnsureSingletonAvailable(ApplicationContext)
            .EnsureInitialized());
    }

    public override void OnCreate() {
        EnsureInitialized(this, EventArgs.Empty); //Raise event
        base.OnCreate();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, it works.
However, can you explain why to use `event`? I made without it, just added `await` in my workaround and it worked.

Comment: @Ghosthack Because it is advised to avoid using `async void` except for event handlers. `OnCreate` is not an event handler. Reference [Async/Await - Best Practices in Asynchronous Programming](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj991977.aspx)